# Функция Recover и обработка invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

Tags: golang

Как обрабатывать ошибки указателей:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xc0000005 code=0x0 addr=0x40 pc=0x6030d2]
```

Читал в документации что `recover` восстанавливает нормальную работу программы Go при панике, но если это произошло с операциями выделения памяти то тут уже ничего не поможет, "*горел сарай, гори и хата*". Как бесконечно обрабатывать ошибки указателей при помощи `recover`? Или тут `recover` вообще не нужен?

Answer (score 0):

recover не то чтобы восстанавливает нормальную работу программы - эта функция позволяет понять что произошло что-то непредвиенное и самостоятельно работу восстановить, если это возможно.

Например если программа обрабатывает кучу запросов и при обработке одного из них произошла ошибка - можно вернуть ошибку, а другие запросы продолжат работу.

1. recover работает только при вызове из defer.
2. recover работает на ошибки только в той же горутине, в которой потом будет defer обрабатываться.

Пример НЕПРАВИЛЬНЫЙ (вызов без defer) - в момент вызова recover проверяет что сейчас никаких исключений не обрабатывается и просто возвращает nil, т.е. в обычном ходе выполнения программы смысла не имеет. Ошибка остается не перехваченной:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    err := recover()
    fmt.Println("TEST RECOVER:", err)

    var a *int
    fmt.Println(a)
    fmt.Println(*a)
}
```

Пример НЕПРАВИЛЬНЫЙ (ошибка в другой горутине):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    defer func() {
        err := recover()
        fmt.Println("TEST RECOVER:", err)
    }()

    var a *int
    fmt.Println(a)
    go func() {
        fmt.Println(*a)
    }()
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
}
```

Пример работающий:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    defer func() {
        err := recover()
        fmt.Println("TEST RECOVER:", err)
    }()

    var a *int
    fmt.Println("еще выполняется")
    fmt.Println(*a)
    fmt.Println("уже не выполнится")
}
```

Обработку ошибок можно сделать комплексной и вынести в какую-то отдельную функцию. Например так

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func handleError() {
    err := recover()
    fmt.Println("TEST RECOVER:", err)
}

func main() {
    defer handleError()
    var a *int
    fmt.Println("еще выполняется")
    fmt.Println(*a)
    fmt.Println("уже не выполнится")
}
```